# 'In the event of fire' or 'in the event of a fire'?

Tags: grammaticality, differences, articles, indefinite-articles, zero-article

> 1. In the event of fire,...
> 2. In the event of a fire,...

I see both variants ondifferent Web pages and I cannot understand which is correct.

Could you please explain it to me.

Comment: Either is correct. A fire is more specific. Fire could be many fires all over the place, a fire is one fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding it should be:

"In case of a fire",is correct; implying that if there is the occurrence or the instance of a fire breaking out...

My feeling is that "in case of fire", may have started as an attempt at brevity and may have been integrated into everyday usage over time.